# I need to format a date in Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime

I have a query in Postgres:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (NOW() - TO_DATE('11-08-2001 10:35:54','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')))
```

The result in something like "63068231613.0091". I don't know how to format the content of `TO_DATE()` to obtain the correct value, which must be the years difference between now() and the data parameter.

**Note:** This select is in a function, so the only thing which can be modified is `TO_DATE('11-08-2001 10:35:54','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`. This content is generated from a Java method, and I have the permission to modify the method, but I am not allowed to modify the SQL function.

Thanks for help!

Comment: If you can't modify the SQL, then why don't you do the formatting in Java? That sounds like a more sensible thing to do anyway, IMO...

Comment: I can modifty the content of "TO_DATE(..)".

Comment: Oh, I see - the Java method isn't what *handles* the returned data, but it's what generates part of the query. Ick. Is there any reason the result *does* have to be formatted in SQL? What's processing the result?

Comment: The java method returns  the string "TO_DATE(..)"

Comment: `the years difference between now() and the data parameter` is an ambiguous definition. There are various ways to interpret that. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify only the "TO_DATE()" and not the rest of the function, then you have to do the formatting in java because you're using "`EXCTRACT EPOCH FROM`" which is in seconds in your case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

If you can modify the SQL function a little, maybe you could try "`EXTRACT YEAR`" instead: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have an error in your `to_date` function. Your formatting string `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'` doesn't match the date you provide `'11-08-2001 10:35:54'`. The correct formatting string is `'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'`.

The other possible problem of you SQL code is that `to_date` function rounds formatted date to days, so `10:35:54` parts of your string will be completely ignored. You could fix it by using `to_timestamp` function instead, though if you only interested in years difference if won't be a problem for you.

As for returned result, your code will return the difference between current time and `11-08-2011 00:00:00` (since time is ignored by `to_date`) in seconds. You can convert it to full years by dividing it to `31536000` in your java application.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with to_timestamp, and the returned value is the difference in seconds between the 2 dates. I think the best idea is to modify the function.